# Standard definition: vector-valued essential support

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, integration, definitions

Let $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$.  If $m=1$ then the essential support of $f$ is a mainstream definition; see [here for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Essential_support).  However, when $m>1$ is the following definition used?

$$
\operatorname{ess-supp}(f)
:=
\bigcap \left\{
K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n
: 
\, K  \mbox{ closed and } [f](x)=0 \mbox{ $\mu$-a.e. } x \not\in K
\right\},
$$
where here $0$ denotes the zero-vector in $\mathbb{R}^D$?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this definition is equivalent to $\operatorname{ess-sup}(f)\otimes 1_{\mathbb{R}^m}$ when identifying $f$ with an element of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})\otimes \mathbb{R}^m$?  But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I think so, yes... But still this doesn't answer the question if the notation/terminology is used or not...